# The Moral of the story

Tags: cryptic-clues

So, I was just preparing some cryptic clues because I was bored. I wanted to separate a few of these from the others so that there would be a nice final answer. However, they have all got mixed up. Your task is to make two more clues from the answers (because meta-cryptics!) and then tell me the final answer. You already know what the question is.

> Small and down is not fast(4)
>   Nudge a purse(4)
>   Bolts large headless fowl(5)
>   Anger has pet annoyed and cold-blooded(7)
>   Judges gets horrible share(5)
>   Creature seen in Afghani malls(6)

Finally, (8) and (4)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Thanks to [LeppyR64](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56697/4421) for the answer to the fourth clue.  Please upvote their answer as well!*

> Small (**s**) and down (**low**) is not fast (**SLOW**)
>  Nudge (**POKE**) a purse (**poke**) (double definition)
>  Bolts (**LOCKS**) large (**l**) headless fowl (c**ocks**)
>  Anger (**rile**) has pet annoyed (**ept**) and cold-blooded (**REPTILE**) (*per [LeppyR64](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56697/4421)*)
>  Judges (**HEARS**) gets horrible share (anagram of share)
>  Creature (**ANIMAL**) seen in Afgh**ani mal**ls

The two final clues are

> Reptile slow poke = **TORTOISE** (double definition)
>  Animal hears locks = **HARE** ("hair" (locks) sounds like "hare")

which refers to

> The story of *[The Tortoise and the Hare](http://www.storyarts.org/library/aesops/stories/tortoise.html)*

And the answer to the question

> which is stated in the title, is
>  ***Slow and steady wins the race***

Answer (score 7):

Here's GPR's missing clue.

Anger has pet annoyed and cold-blooded(7)

> Anger (RILE) has pet annoyed (EPT) and cold-blooded(7)
>  REPTILE

Comment: Thanks!  I've added this to my answer (with attribution).

Comment: Well done @GentlePurpleRain